# Jenkins unable to connect to Windows Docker Toolbox Daemon

Tags: windows, jenkins, docker-toolbox

I have installed Docker ToolBox for Windows and Jenkins in my Windows 7 Desktop.I am attempting to create a Jenkins Job which will list down docker images available. However, in doing so I am getting the following error :-

**Started by user Nilanjan Dutta
Building on master in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Docker
[Docker] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins1754863637345314489.bat
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Docker>docker images 
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.37/images/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Docker>exit 1 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE**

I have tried adding the jenkins user in "docker users" group but I could not find the group in "Local Users and Groups" in Computer Management. Please refer the image below :-
[image: Local Groups]

My target is ultimately creating a CI pipeline in Jenkins where I need to build my docker image and push it to docker hub. But I am stuck in this phase and unable to proceed.

**Please note that my Jenkins is a standalone installation and not a Docker Container**

Below is my Docker version :-
**Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24302**

I am relatively new to Docker and Jenkins and is unable to proceed due to the above issue.
Any help is immensely appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately did not find any solution to the above..so resorted to running Jenkins as a docker container and deploying node plugin and docker client binaries.

Answer (score 3):

Today I faced the same issue (Windows 10), and solved it in following way:

Get docker toolbox env variables:

Open CMD and type `Docker-machine env default`

You’ll get similar output:

```
SET DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
SET DOCKER_HOST=tcp://172.16.0.102:2376
SET DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\user.docker\machine\machines\default
SET DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=default
SET COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=true
REM Run this command to configure your shell:
REM @FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('Docker-machine env default') DO @%i
```

Open **Jenkins** – **Manage Jenkins** – **Configure System** – Check **Environment variables** check box and add following environment variables with values above:

- `DOCKER_CERT_PATH`
- `DOCKER_HOST`
- `DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME`
- `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY`

Restart Jenkins service and you should be good to go.

Reference: [Jenkins Server with local docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54077205/jenkins-server-with-local-docker)

Comment: Thank you..that worked. also I made it to work by by giving the jenkins user full permission to docker sock process :- sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock

Comment: Docker-machine isn't recognized as a command

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62422143/docker-machine-command-not-found-on-windows-10    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60078434/docker-machine-command-not-found