# docker-machine: command not found

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I recently upgraded Docker Desktop for Mac to version 2.2.0.0, and now when try to run a `docker-machine` command I am getting an error:

```
$ docker-machine --version
```

> docker-machine: command not found

Docker Machine used to be installed with Docker, but it appears in the [latest docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/) that this is no longer the case. What is the replacement or do I need to install Docker Machine from somewhere else?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Docker machine has been removed from later versions of Docker Desktop. Your going to need the docker-toolbox package.

Read here for install and co existence of the packages.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/#docker-toolbox-and-docker-desktop-coexistence

Comment: Docker-toolbox is [deprecated](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/docker-toolbox/). Follow the [installation instructions from the docker-machine repo](https://github.com/docker/machine/releases).

Comment: for the love of! pick one docker and stick to it.

Answer (score 18):

For **Windows**, if you have **chocolatey** installed, you follow the steps:

1. open a command shell with "**Run as Administrator**" selected (I tested this on my work laptop).
2. run "**choco install docker-machine**"

Comment: I literally say that I'm using a Mac in the question. Why add this here?

Comment: I came here from a search and seen the title "docker-machine: command not found". I am Windows user. Somebody might drop like me and find this helpful.

Comment: I'm a windows user.  Thanks for this!

Comment: @wogsland, "I literally say that I'm using a Mac in the question. Why add this here?," maybe this expectation is short-sighted, seeing the problem is not specific to only one OS

Answer (score 14):

Docker machine is now merged into the docker command, So instead of using

```
docker-machine init
```

Use

```
docker swarm init
```

And instead of

```
docker-machine join
```

Use

```
docker swarm join
```

for more command just use this:

```
docker swarm --help
```

Comment: What about `docker-machine create`? I guess we should install `docker-machine` after all.

Answer (score 11):

If you already have docker-desktop & want the `docker-machine` command, then `brew install docker-machine` does the trick.

My versions of the binaries in `usr/local/bin/docker` and `usr/local/bin/docker-compose` did not change, & the version of the docker client & server, but I got the `docker-machine` binary extra.

run `unset ${!DOCKER_*}` if you want to use docker-desktop.

The docker docs are a bit confusing because they seem to address the case where you have docker-machine first, not the case where you have desktop first.

Comment: how to install docker-machine on windows?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try brew to install it as they removed docker-machine from v2.2.0?

```
brew install docker-machine
```

Answer (score 2):

You basically need to install Docker Machine first on your local machine. Reference :- https://github.com/docker/machine/releases

```
$ curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.16.0/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` >/tmp/docker-machine &&
chmod +x /tmp/docker-machine &&
sudo cp /tmp/docker-machine /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

Answer (score 1):

Try and run this command on bash:

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.16.0/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` >/tmp/docker-machine && chmod +x /tmp/docker-machine && sudo cp /tmp/docker-machine /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

[Click here to know more about docker-machine installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CCfL.png)

It worked for me.

Comment: I highly recommend not simply copying and pasting a command that downloads and executes an external script from a random stackoverflow post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (both inside, and outside of container):

```
ss -nputl
```