# docker-machine command not found on windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, docker-machine

I have recently installed docker machine using using git bash in windows 10 from following this url: https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/tag/v0.16.2

And when I'm running "docker-machine version" command on git bash, it is working fine and giving current version of docker machine, but when I'm running same command on command prompt, it is not recognizing the command

Answer (score 1):

Git bash uses a Linux environment isolated from Windows, so you can't run Linux programs from Windows. You need to use Docker solely within Git bash.

For this purpose (using Linux for development under Windows), I recommend you to use [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) instead of Git bash which is meant for Git use only.

If you are more familiar with Windows, you can develop and run Docker apps locally on Windows without Linux, by using either [Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/), or [Docker Desktop for Windows](https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows)

Comment: Hi, actually I'm beginner in this. I already have docker desktop on my windows system and I was not able to install docker machine on my windows system directly that's why I used git bash to install it. Now can you tell me how to proceed with creating docker-machine on my windows system

Comment: @Ankit You just do everything inside Git bash then you're fine. You just can't do it under Windows command prompt.
If you're learning Docker then why do you use `docker-machine`? Its for production use only. The command that you work with most of the times should be `docker` (which you can do under Windows command prompt after you installed Docker for Desktop).

Comment: Okay, Thanks. And I need one more help, I've tried creating docker-machine using git bash but it got stuck at "Running pre-create checks.." for about 20-30 mins. Is it usually take that much time to create machine?