# how to specify arguments like --tls-verify=false on Jenkins Docker withRegistry

Tags: docker, jenkins, nexus

I am having a hard time determining how to specify arguments, like `--tls-verify=false` when using `docker.withRegistry` in Jenkins.  I have a private Nexus Repository where I want to push my container image to.  The private repository does not have TLS so I need to disable it.

I am able to push from the command line by logging in like: `docker login --tls-verify=false -u mylogin my-registry:10032`

```
    stage('Push image') {
        docker.withRegistry('http://my-registry:10030/', 'nexus-credentials') {
            app.push("latest")
        }
    }
```

This translates in the Jenkins console output to: `docker login -u mylogin -p ******** http://my-registry:10030/`

Which fails because of needing to disable TLS.  How can I use `withRegistry` while specifying an argument?

Comment: Have you tried it without passing `'nexus-credentials'` to `withRegistry()`. According to Jenkins: "For a Docker Registry which requires authentication, add a "Username/Password" Credentials item from the Jenkins home page and use the Credentials ID as a second argument to `withRegistry()`."

Comment: Hey I think that's exactly what I'm doing. nexus-credentials is the ID that was added from the Jenkins homepage. Just need to figure out how to pass an argument with it.

Comment: It seems that you need to set `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=0` Jenkins variable. Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54093480/7934282).

Comment: Thanks trying that now and will let you know!